# get stream-io response data is changed to string from json object

Tags: getstream-io

Payload sending to getStream.io server

```
{
    "feed": {
        "actor": 1986,
        "created_at": 1455690430,
        "foreign_id": "1986",
        "object": {
            "full_name": "Harsewak Singh",
            "login": "harsewak",
            "pic_url": "https:\/\/qbapi.dekhdekh.com\/blobs\/b6e113a29bb34905a14a520917f6da0a00",
            "user": 1986
        },
        "post": {
            "created_at": 1455690430,
            "message": "Hey! How's everyone?",
            "type": "text"
        },
        "to": ["flat:global"],
        "verb": "post"
    },
    "feed_type": "flat",
    "user_id": 1986
}
```

But when data is returned value of object isn't same as sent

It's as follows

```
"object": 
    "{u'login': u'harsewak', u'pic_url': u'https://qbapi.dekhdekh.com/blobs/b6e113a29bb34905a14a520917f6da0a00', u'full_name': u'Harsewak Singh', u'user': 1986}"
```

Q. Why u' is added in response after replaceing double quotes ("login")?

Comment: which API client are you using to send the data?

Comment: We are using laravel api to interact with getstream.io.

Answer (score 0):

Sending nested data in the object field is currently not supported by Stream's APIs.

if you are using Laravel and Eloquent, you should integrate your models like documented here: https://github.com/GetStream/stream-laravel#eloquent-integration This way you will get serialization and deserialization working for free.